# run different code when required instead of passed to node CLI directly

Tags: node.js

I assume it's possible to differentiate on whether a file is required or passed to node directly?

E.g.:

```
//foo.js
if( ???? ){
  console.log( "This file was required" );
else{
  console.log( "This file was run directly" );
}
```

Would output "This file was required" when some other file requires it like this

```
//baz.js
var foo = require('foo.js');
```

and would output "This file was run directly" when passed to node directly:

```
$ node foo.js
```

What exactly should the conditional be like?

Comment: `__filename === undefined`

Comment: @generalhenry `typeof __filename` returns `string` for both tests.

Comment: ahh, nvm, I misread, that one is for the repl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `module.parent` to see if it's being run globally or required.

The [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent) states

> The module that required this one.

Meaning if it wasn't required, then `module.parent` doesn't exist.

```
if (module.parent) {
    console.log('File is being required.');
} else {
    console.log('File is being run directly.');
}
```